# SL Firing a Command from Within a ListItem Data Template, to a ViewModel for the MainPage.xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, command

I may be making this more complicated than necessary ... but here goes.

I have my MainPage.xaml, in there I have references to two other UserControl's, ResultsView, and DetailsView.

Inside of the ResultsView, I have a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection of custom items, I have a DataTemplate that is rendering each item. The item has a CaseID, and when I click on it, it's displayed as a HyperlinkButton, I need a Command I've set in the MainPageViewModel to fire, which handles changing the visibility to hide the ResultsView, and show the DetailsView.

How do I bind the Command of the Hyperlinkbutton to the Command located in my MainPageViewModel?

Thanks in advance!

edit for clarification:

MainPage.xaml

```
<resultsView:ResultsView/>
<detailsView:DetailsView/>
```

Each of the two views (ResultsView & DetailsView) have their own ViewModel. So I'm going from my DataTemplate which resides in a ListBox inside my ResultsView, I need to go up to the MainPageViewModel, an extra step than your answer mentioned. Tried your method naming my MainPage.xaml to Name="mainPage", and using that as the ElementName in my HyperlinkButton, but no luck. I'll do some research on the RelativeSource option and see if I can make that work.

Thanks for your help so far.

edit 2: Forgot to add that the DataTemplate is in a ResourceDictionary, not in the ResultsView.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the specific details, not all of which you've told us, but I can give you some examples.

Let's say that your `DataTemplate` for the custom items resides in the XAML of the `ResultsView` user control.  That's a good spot for it but you might have put it in a resource dictionary.

As you say, the `ListBox` is bound to the collection of custom items.  Let's further assume that the custom items collection is itself a property in your `MainPageViewModel`.  And you've said clearly that the command you want to bind to is also in `MainPageViewModel`.

So the problem, which is a very common one, is that you are working inside a template associated with a binding to a collection, and so your `DataContext` is a custom item.  It is no longer the main view-model itself.  That's great as you show appropriate properties of the custom item like `CaseID`.  But it's not great when you want to **escape** to the top-level of view-model.

If what I've said is true, then the `ResultsView` user control is in fact probably bound to the `MainPageViewModel` because you haven't "drilled into" the custom items collection yet.  So, what you need to do is find a way using the binding syntax to reference the `ResultsView` user control from inside the `DataTemplate` for the `ListBox`.  If you can do that, then you've escaped the collection.

There are two main approaches to do this:

- `ElementName` syntax
- `RelativeSource` syntax

I'll describe `ElementName` syntax and you can look up the other one.

Part 1) Name your `ResultsView` `UserControl` element like this:

```
<UserControl ....
    Name="resultsView">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Part 2) Inside your `DataTemplate` where you are defining the appearance of the hyperlink use the `ElementName` syntax to refer to that element:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemDetailsCommand, ElementName=resultsView}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

So first we use `ElementName` to get the `ResultsView` `UserControl` element, and then we have a path with two pieces: the first piece is the `DataContext` property of the `ResultsView` which gives us the `MainPageViewModel` (yeah!), and then the property of the command we want to invoke.

That's one way to "escape" the binding and issue commands found at a higher level in the view-model.

Comment: Hi Rick, I'll add a bit more clarification for you.